# How should I structure a Gradle project containing non-sourcecode artifacts?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle project which contains (among other things, like some Java classes) a directory full of [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) templates which will need to be deployed to a remote server.

Right now I have the templates in `src/main/velocity` and I have a Sync task named `syncTemplates` that syncs this directory with another location on the local machine.

I need to modify this build so that the templates get synced with a directory on a remote machine using SCP. What is the "Gradle way" of doing this? I'm still a bit unclear on the relationship between configurations, artifacts, and sourcesets, so I'm not sure if there's an elegant way to make this happen or if I should just use an ant task with some hard-coded (project-relative) paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this. You could create a configuration for the SCP dependencies and then use the Ant task to transfer the files.

```
configurations { 
    scp 
} 

dependencies { 
    scp 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.8.2' 
} 

task syncTemplates << { 
    ant.taskdef(name: 'scp', classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp', classpath: configurations.scp.asPath) 
    ant.scp(remoteToDir: 'user@host:someDir', password: 'password') {
        fileset(dir: 'src/main/velocity') {
            include(name: '**/*.vm')
        }
    }
}
```